# How does target="framename" work when iframe DOM has changed

Tags: javascript, html, dom, iframe, target

I know iframes are evil, but mine is legacy app n I need to use iframes in it. So...

I need to create n display tabs of iframes dynamically for my web app. All frame sources are intra-domain so full traversal n access within the frames possible.

The problem with iframes n the DOM is that these iframes register as window.frames.framename, so I will have an array of those objects in the "frames" object.

My requirement states that the "active" frame must have the name "form". So I change that iframe attribute when setting that frame as active. But this doesn't reflect in the DOM as window.frames.form, so I change that too manually by setting the current frame object like this:
frames.form = my_frame.content Window

All this works fine n I'm able to now access everything in n out of the active "form" iframe properly.

The problem now is with my links in the main page that have target="form". The target is not being recognized as the latest set (active) iframe with the name "form", n hence that link when clicked opens up in a new window/tab in the browser. This behavior is in all browsers except firefox. (Firefox does the required thing: open those links in the latest form iframe)

I suppose I don't have the knowledge of how the browser manipulates such changes in the DOM related to iframes. So any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

UPDATE:
Here's a simplified code (note: not original code): http://jsfiddle.net/u4VJL/5/

```
 function AddNewTab(e) {
     $('#list').attr('id', 'nolist').attr('name', 'nolist');
     $('#form').attr('id', 'noform').attr('name', 'noform');

     $(document.body).append('<iframe id="list" name="list" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" class="form" style="width:22%"></iframe>');
     $(document.body).append('<iframe id="form" name="form" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" class="form" style="width:74%"></iframe>');
     frames.list = $('#list')[0].contentWindow;
     frames.form = $('#form')[0].contentWindow;

     return false;
 }
 $('#addnew').click(AddNewTab);
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:

- Click the "Add new tab" link once.
- Click "Sample link" - and that href will load in the right frame
  named "form".
- Click "Add new tab" again. A new set off iframes should show up.
- Click "Sample link" again. The page should now load in the 2nd right
  frame, but it loads in first.
- NOTE: Browsers with this issue (that I've tested in): Google Chrome,
  IE8. Firefox does not have this issue.

Comment: Hmm that should work... when you change another `iframe` to have `name=frame` are you sure you are taking the name off the prior one first? Can you post some code here or on fiddle?

Comment: Yup I am. I am actually using Knockout.js here. So it takes care of it, definitely. I'll try to post a sample code in a while so that you can see what I'm talking about. Thanks!

Comment: give an id to the iframe same as the name attribute

Comment: Also, I was thinking before that Knockout could be the reason, but I'm sure now that it is not, because if the entire (iframe) element was supposed to be refreshed/created again n again whenever there is an "observable" change, it would've messed with my contents in the iframe, which does not happen. so.. anyway.. Sample code's on the way.

Comment: And just to be clear, your parent `iframe` is the one with the links and the `target` links pointing at `form`?

Comment: @rps ... oh yes, i have.. whenever i change the name, i change the "id" attribute too to the same (name) value.

Comment: @dave: my parent page, if that's the same as parent iframe? .. anyway, i think it will be easier for you guys if i post some code. Please wait. And thanks for the help.

Comment: @DaveStein Sorry couldn't do it sooner, but... I've updated my question with a simplified sample code, where the issue can be seen (in Chrome browser). Thanks!

Comment: @DaveStein You mentioned at the very beginning to make sure that `name` is set/unset properly for the concerned `iframes`. If you meant the DOM property (see my answer) and/or the HTML attribute, please post it as an answer so that I can mark it as one. Sorry if I didn't get the message earlier.
(I won't mark mine as the answer until I hear back from you :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frame name` indeed. This works (in Firefox, Chrome, and IE8 n above):

```
    function AddNewTab(e) {
        $('#list').attr('id', 'nolist').attr('name', 'nolist');
        $('#form').attr('id', 'noform').attr('name', 'noform');
        if (frames.list) frames.list.name = 'nolist';
        if (frames.form) frames.form.name = 'noform';

        $(document.body).append('<iframe id="list" name="list" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" class="form" style="width:22%"></iframe>');
        $(document.body).append('<iframe id="form" name="form" src="" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" frameborder="1" class="form" style="width:74%"></iframe>');
        frames.list = $('#list')[0].contentWindow;
        frames.form = $('#form')[0].contentWindow;

        frames.list.name = 'list';
        frames.form.name = 'form';

        return false;
    }
    $('#addnew').click(AddNewTab);
```

Working code here: http://jsfiddle.net/krislogy/u4VJL/8/

((PS: tchh!! I swear I had tried this but couldn't make it work before. Anyway, I guess I was wrong when I **thought** I tried it. Thanks all!!))

Answer (score 0):

you need to use live:
`$('#addnew').live("click", AddNewTab);`

uhh, it was a wrong answer, i think you need to look this way:

```
$("a[target=form]").click( function(){
    $("#form").last().attr("src", $("a[target=form]").attr("href"));
    $("#form").reload();
    return false;
});
```

this works

Comment: Can you add more explanation ?

Comment: Why use `live`? You know that is deprecated right? (And removed in jQuery 1.9)

Comment: Aah well, I know I could manipulate the "a" tags with target=form in DOM, but it won't be feasible for me due to the complexity of my app. But still I'll +1 your answer, as it is indeed an alternative (but unfortunately not the one I can implement on a larger scale).